# Workmanager no se ejecuta tras reiniciar el equipo

Tags: android

Tengo un Workmanager ya funcionando de manera periódica de forma correcta cada 15 minutos, pero si reinicio el teléfono ya no se vuelve a ejecutar de forma automática.

```
WorkManager mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
PeriodicWorkRequest mRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder( workmanager.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();        
mWorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("monitor", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,mRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando reninicias o apagas tu dispositivo, la aplicaciòn se elimina de del administrador de tareas, lo que debes realizar es lo siguiente:
Tu clase `workmanager` debe extender de la clase `Worker` :

```
public class workmanager extends Worker {
   ...
   ...
}
```

Pero tambièn debes definir dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml :

**Esto provocara que el `WorkManager` ejecute su servicio nuevamente después de reiniciar el dispositivo.**